# Python MySQL connector select with variable

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I've this little query :

```
id = 'TESTID'
sql = "SELECT ID,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE ID = %s"
cursor.execute(sql,(id))
```

and i'm having the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TESTID''' at line 1
```

I know this is something about double quotes. I've multiple other query that runs perfectly, but they have like 3 parameters

example :

```
id = 'TESTID'
GR = 'TEST'
name = 'HELLO'
last_name = 'WORLD'
sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID,GR,name,last_name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(id,gr,name,last_name))
```

This one don't have 3 double quote at the beginning and 3 others at the end and runs perfectly so i dont know what to do now.

Thanks you.

Comment: try `sql = "SELECT ID,PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE ID = ?"`

Answer (score 4):

One thing you should remember in python is  that `(7)` is the same as `7`. For a tuple of length 1, you have to say `(7,)` (note that important trailing comma).

So change this line:
`cursor.execute(sql,(id))` to `cursor.execute(sql,(id,))`.